# Parse popen3 output with some JSON content

Tags: json, ruby, popen3

I'm pretty new to Ruby and I'm running a command using `Open3.popen3()` in the following fashion:

```rb
_, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3("<command>")
raise "<command> failed: #{stderr.read}" if wait_thr.value != 0
```

The expected **stdout** (`stdout.read`) follows the next structure (note that the number of elements of the array can vary):

```
Some log line of plain text:
[{'foo': 'bar', 'fooz': '1'}, {'spam': 'ham', 'eggs': '5'}]
```

When I read the **stdout** it returns a String, which of course is the expected class, but I would like to process it a little bit to be able to convert/parse it into JSON. What I tried was:

```rb
list = stdout.read.sub! 'Some log line of plain text:', ''
JSON.parse(list)
```

but it doesn't work:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.6.1/lib/json/common.rb:216:in `parse': 451: unexpected token at '{'foo': 'bar', 'fooz': '1'}, {'spam': 'ham', 'eggs': '5'}]' (JSON::ParserError)
```

Is there a way to do it that is not too hacky? TIA!

Comment: Strings in JSON must be delimited by a double-quote character `"`, not a single-quote character `'`. As such, what you have there is not JSON but some other format. Check the documentation of the program you are calling to find the actual format of its output.

Comment: @HolgerJust you are right! I have just find&replaced single quotes by double quotes and now it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, just found a way to do so:

```rb
list = stdout.read.sub! 'Some log line of plain text:', ''
JSON.parse(list.gsub('\'', '"'))
```

Not sure if it's the best way to do it but good enough for me!